# Parallel process Python

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, subprocess, multiprocessing

I'm doing a robot that can be remotely controlled using raspberry and python.

I have a Flask Rest API running in a server that sends commands to the robot when the user press the buttons. Say I press the button to move forward, the robot can only move if all sensors don't detect any near object. The robot continues running until the stop button is pressed or any sensor reaches an object.

My doubt is:
How can I keep the API code listening to any request, and keep the sensors measuring the distances at the same time? If the robot is running, I thought I should do a "while True" until the sensor reaches a object, but it will lock the program and if I press the stop button it won't stop because of the endless loop...

Whenever the robot is moving to any direction, I need the sensors to be active and the API listening at the same time.

I searched about multiprocessing and subprocess modules, but not exactly what I need to do.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: did you explore threading module of python?

Comment: you can start a thread in `while run_flag: if detect_object: do_move()`, and `run_flag` can be gotten from `thread_global_var/pipe/cache/db` that set from `request`.

Answer (score 1):

Mulitple threading probably what you want.

Below is a very simple sample for you, you can see thread 2 print '2' on screen first.

```
import threading
import time

def loopfunc1():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('1')

def loopfunc2():
    print('2')

# launch thread 1
t = threading.Thread(target=loopfunc1)
t.start()

# not waiting thread 1 finish
# launch thread 2
# thread 2 print '2' on screen first
t = threading.Thread(target=loopfunc2)
t.start()
```